# NPM Install, move files with a build script

Tags: node.js, npm

I have built a custom npm package that is essentially a list of dependencies, a gulp file, and a configuration file for it. The idea is that I can run `npm install <path-to-git-repo>` to pull in gulp whenever I start a new development project.

However, I would like the gulp file and config file to be moved into the current directory, and not remain inside of `node_modules`. I have tried to accomplish this with the install script in my `package.json` file listed below, but it didn't seem to do anything. The files I'm trying to move are included in the `files` section of `package.json`.

```
"scripts":
    {
      "install": "mv gulpfile.js ./ && mv gulp.config.json ./"
    },
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

For something like this I think it would be much easier to have 1 source gulp file and specify the dependent gulp file(s) wherever you're installing them.  [example blog](http://macr.ae/article/splitting-gulpfile-multiple-files.html)

Also, just to point out, `install` is typically [considered an anti-pattern](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#note-install-scripts-are-an-antipattern)

But to answer your exact question, this command `mv gulpfile.js ./ && mv gulp.config.json ./`  looks to me like you're saying move gulpfile.js (which is already in the root directory), into `./` (which is the same directory).  Check your source directory actually contains the gulpfile.js by running the command yourself on the command line

Comment: Thanks for that link, it's pretty helpful. What is the current working directory in which the install script runs?

Comment: by default it starts in the node_modules/.bin directory .  [See here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path) for the explanation.